# Netbeans + derby + hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, derby

I'm following http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html tute to setup hibernate with derby in netbeans IDE.

Netbeans fails to create hibernate.reveng.xml with error : "Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate Configuration file. Please verify the database connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml"

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:G:\projects\Java\DesktopApplication1\db;create=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and database is accessible on this path.

Any idea?

Comment: Tried with mysql and it worked, maybe my url is wrong?

Comment: Found this in netbeans log file:

java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database G:\projects\Java\DesktopApplication1\db.

All connections are closed, looks like netbeans makes more then one connection.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> Found this in netbeans log file: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database G:\projects\Java\DesktopApplication1\db.

Just a guess but you have maybe an SQL client still connected. Or maybe the database didn't shutdown properly. Try to specify a [`shutdown=true`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/tdevdvlp40464.html) in the connection string.

Actually, my suggestion would be to use Derby in server mode, NetBeans provides excellent support for it. See [Working with the Java DB (Derby) Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. No, I tried to do this after restarting computer, still same error. Tried shutdown=true as well. I use derby only because it can be embedded, otherwise I would use MySQL. This app should be able to work in network, many apps on same db, then I would use server mode.

Comment: @umpirsky: I don't know. FWIW, I'm using Derby with Hibernate (in-memory, embedded, server mode) and I don't face the problem you're mentioning. Actually, I don't face any problem, Derby is a very nice database, robust and is well supported by Hibernate.

Comment: Why it's not in the upper list on http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases ?

Comment: @umpirsky: I don't know. Do whatever you want, I'm just letting readers know that Derby works well with Hibernate.

Comment: OK, will give it a deeper test ;)

Comment: In server mode it works well, no locking and netbeans generates nice pojos. 

Except, for generated primary keys it puts  <generator class="assigned" /> instead  <generator class="identity" />, that took some time to figure out.

And, netbeans does not generate foreign key references <many-to-one... in xml or java pojos. Any idea?