# Which Hibernate compatible embedded database to use for Java Swing application?

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I will be implementing a Java Swing app. At first, I wanted to use Apache Derby DB, because I needed an embedded DB.

But it turned out that it does not plays nice with hibernate (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1003258&p=2433546#p2433546, [Netbeans + derby + hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322575/netbeans-derby-hibernate)).

Hibernate ignores auto generated keys and foreign keys...

Can you recommend some DB that can be embedded and nicely used with Hibernate, or tell me how to make Derby work well with Hibernate?

Comment: You're doing something wrong, Derby just works for me (and I switched to Derby after database corruption problems with HSQLDB).

Comment: @Pascal Thivent  Derby does not (yet) support generation of key relations https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2433549

Does it generates for you? I manage to create primary keys, but foreign relations no.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer h2, the "Hypersonic 2". See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison for a comparsion.

Answer (score 2):

Try Hypersonic SQL.

Comment: I saw it's fast. Do you know any gui client better then HSQL database manager? I don't like creating foreign keys and auto increment values from plain SQL. Maybe I should start :)

Comment: How else do you propose to do so?

Comment: It works good. Embeded mode is a bit difficult for development, but you can develop in server mode, and embed it on production. I think HSQL can be the right choice.

Comment: Why not vote the question up as well?  I'm glad you accepted it, but the vote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of MySQL embedded

Comment: SQLite could do the job, it's free and embeddable

Comment: It's embeded, but It's not supported by hibernate http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases

Comment: with this little addition

http://arnoraps.tweakblogs.net/blog/3146/hibernate-with-sqlite.html

SQLite gets the support you need

Answer (score 0):

All in all, I tested Derby and HSQL, tried to make simple hibernate CRUD app with netbeans.

Both of them set   which you need to manually change to   if you don't want to worry about generating primary keys, which is not a big deal.

But, derby pojos and mapping files totally ignore foreign table references, didn't tried to add them by hand, but netbeans does not generate them.

HSQL does not have this problem.

People are complaining about corrupted data and inconsistency, they are migrating from HSQL to Derby and from Derby to HSQL.

I don't know if HSQL is good for me and my production use. I would use it in embeded mode for desktop app, and one version for network usage, where it will be in server mode probably, so both.

All suggestions are welcome.